# Google AppEngine - 500 Server Error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gradle, google-cloud-endpoints

I am using Android Studio to create a GAE Server Module. It's running perfectly on the local server, but after deploying there appears this error.
I've read that I have to compile with Java 7, but my gradle-file says, I am compiling with Java 7:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.17'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.17'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.17'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.17'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
}
```

Comment: check the app logs in the developer console for server side errors and edit your question to add them.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it: It wasn't compiled correctly. I completely removed java8 and installed java7. I worked then.